# How to put icon on string in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have array string and I want to put icons inside that string like this,

```
var arr = ['lorem ipsum dolor select icon '+Icons(Icons.search)+' blablabla...'];
```

But I got error

```
The argument type 'Icons' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
```

How I can solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `Widgets` inside your `String` variable, what you can do is use the `Row` widget, like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text('lorem ipsum dolor select icon '),
    Icon(Icons.search),
    Text(' blablabla...')
  ],
);
```

More info here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html

Answer (score 4):

Just solved the same problem by using RichText and TextSpan

```
new RichText(
    text: new TextSpan(children: [
        TextSpan(text: 'Some random string', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        WidgetSpan(
            child: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black45),
        ),
        TextSpan(text: 'Some random string.', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    ]),
)
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a list with the type of dynamic

```
List<dynamic> myList = <dynamic>[Text('Hello'),Icon(Icons.add),Text('World')];
```

if you wish to use it inside your **widget** **tree**. you can to it by using the **row** or **column** widget:

```
`Column(children: myList)` OR `Row(children: myList)`
```